# Find a value of a list in list and write a comment like duplicated python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

list = [[2, 3, **4**], [6, 7, **4**], [10, 11, **12**], [14, 15, 16], [18, 19, **12**]]

I wont give a variable to code it will check the lists fourth value and if its duplicated in another list code will append a "found" string

list = [[2, 3, 4, "found"], [6, 7, 4, "found"], [10, 11, 12, "found"], [14, 15, 16], [18, 19, 12, "found"]]

I tried a lot but couldn't find any solutions.

```
listm = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 4], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]

c = 4

for i, alt_list in enumerate(listm):
  if c in alt_list:
   listm[i].append("found")

print(listm)
```

Comment: Explain why does `[18, 19, 12, "found"]` match the `c = 4 and c in alt_list` condition?

Comment: The code was working fine what your desired output is?

Comment: liste = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 4], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 12]]
duplicated values are 4 and 12 then the result must be like that liste = [[1, 2, 3, 4, "found"], [5, 6, 7, 4, "found"], [9, 10, 11, 12, "found"], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 12, "found"]]

Comment: I wont give a variable to code it will check the lists fourth value and if its duplicated in another list code will append a "found" string

Comment: @user289017, ok, move this explanations to your question's description

Comment: Are the duplicates that you are interested in always in the last position in the lists? Always in corresponding positions? If the duplicates appear in another position, is the word `"found"` in another position as well? You haven't fully described the problem.

Comment: yes at last position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an auxiliary dict to count occurrences of the last value of inner lists:

```
lst = [[2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 4], [10, 11, 12], [14, 15, 16], [18, 19, 12]]
counts = {}
for sub_l in lst:
    counts[sub_l[-1]] = 1 if sub_l[-1] not in counts else sub_l[-1] + 1
lst = [l + ['found'] if counts[l[-1]] > 1 else l for l in lst]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 'found'], [6, 7, 4, 'found'], [10, 11, 12, 'found'], [14, 15, 16], [18, 19, 12, 'found']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an auxiliary dict to count occurrences of the last value of inner lists:

```
lst = [[2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 4], [10, 11, 12], [14, 15, 16], [18, 19, 12]]
counts = {}
for sub_l in lst:
    counts[sub_l[-1]] = 1 if sub_l[-1] not in counts else sub_l[-1] + 1
lst = [l + ['found'] if counts[l[-1]] > 1 else l for l in lst]

print(lst)
```

---

```
[[2, 3, 4, 'found'], [6, 7, 4, 'found'], [10, 11, 12, 'found'], [14, 15, 16], [18, 19, 12, 'found']]
```

Comment: So I cant use import library I must solve it without libraries

I must write the code like that

for i, lst in enumerate(listm)
    s = set(lst)
    for j, el in enumerate(listm)
        if i != j and s.intersection(el) and 'found' not in lst
            out.append(lst + ['found'])

            break
        end
    else

        out.append(lst)

       end
       end 
Print(out)

Comment: @user289017, ok, you should have mentioned that from the start, but see my update

Comment: KeyError:12
ScriptModuleService/var/prepare-for-execute/512dce13-4789-48e0-be8f-13ea6e0370a4/Ungrouped files/adsdasd.hsl3(5):<module>
ScriptModuleService/var/prepare-for-execute/512dce13-4789-48e0-be8f-13ea6e0370a4/Ungrouped files/adsdasd.hsl3(5):<listcomp>

I m getting this error sir

Comment: @user289017, the above solution works without errors, check your code for typos.

Comment: This works but your original counter-based approach was of course more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counter-based approach:

```
from collections import Counter
lists = [[2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 4], [10, 11, 12], [14, 15, 16], [18, 19, 12]]
final_counts = Counter(sublist[-1] for sublist in lists)
for sublist in lists:
    if final_counts[sublist[-1]] > 1:
        sublist.append("found")
print(lists)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 'found'], [6, 7, 4, 'found'], [10, 11, 12, 'found'], [14, 15, 16], [18, 19, 12, 'found']]
```